# Is there a hotel search engine which allows one to exclude shared rooms?

Tags: bookings, hotels, price, booking.com, accommodation-search-engines

The main big hotel search websites I know: http://www.booking.com/ http://www.hotels.com/ http://www.laterooms.com/ list many "hotels" which also sell single beds in dorm rooms. Try searching for London for 1 person, and sort by price, you'll see that the cheapest offers are mostly single beds in shared dorm rooms. Its impossible to find the cheapest offer for the whole private room without examining each offer manually.

You could filter out "hostel" style properties, but that misses out on many facilities branding as "hostels" but having cheap private rooms, so its not an ideal solution. And on Booking.com even that won't work, as it still leaves many which brand themselves there as a "hotel", but have shared dorm rooms, and prices are shown for a bed in such a dorm room, and not a whole private room.

Is there really not a website which has cheap hotels (regardless of if they call themselves a "hotel" or a "hostel", as often this division is blurry and arbitrary, and doesn't specify what type of rooms the facility has), and sorts the the price of the cheapest whole private room?

The website should list most hotels, and not only hostels - websites like hostels.com hostelz.com hostelsclub.com hostelbookers.com hostelworld.com gomio.com filter by private rooms, but they don't show most real hotels (many of which have sometimes quite cheap offers), only hostels. These hostel websites list only max. 100-300 properties in London, while Booking.com has 2359 and Hotels.com has 1614, so a website listing hotels should have at least a thousand in London, as opposed to only 300 hostels.

Comment: Airbnb has a 'private room' filter for searches

Comment: I used to be able to tick something in booking.com and get the option to search for hostels beds or rooms. I can not find it at this time.

Comment: The default search on booking.com is for two people. AFAIK this will give you a private room every time.

Comment: Couldn't you look up based on how many people you have?

Comment: @PressTilty The author is presumably looking for the cheapest private room for one person, namely himself.

Comment: @Calchas: wrong, I just searched for 2 people for tonight in London on Booking.com, then sorted by Price, and the cheapest offer is "Bed in 6-Bed Female Dormitory Room". The sorting by price is also stupid, as it shows a "58$ per person single room", before a "72$ for up to 2 people" offer, which would obviously be cheaper in total (I searched for 2 people).

Comment: The proposed duplicate is a few years older and not updated. I would suggest first updating that one and then to close vote this one.

Answer (score 12):

I was searching for a room with booking.com, and when it displayed results, it included shared rooms. And just under the "order by" pane, there was a pane with a text and link:

[image: Your results include some shared accommodations, such as dormitory beds. Show private rooms only]

Clicking this link filters out shared rooms.

Comment: I know this option, sadly it won't help. It still show shared rooms in hostels. It has been working this broken way for years, have no idea why Booking not fixing it.

Comment: Does not work on map view at least

Comment: Does it exist from anroid on app or on website? Don't have a pc when traveling

Answer (score 1):

[Trivago](http://trivago.com/) offers the ability to search for rooms suitable for 1 person. It will sometimes return 2 person rooms as well, but will show the price a single guest has to pay.